# Importing CLR in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I created a plugin and I added my separate Python file (added in plugin path itself) in the created QGIS plugin. In that separate Python file, I called a DLL file like below,

```
import sys
import clr
class pythonCall:
    def callMethod():
       clr.AddReference(r"D:\\K\\bin\\Debug\\ClassFile.dll")
       from ClassFile import DynamicCalc
       calc=DynamicCalc()
       print calc.getValue()
```

I called the separate Python file in my QGIS plugin Python like below,

```
from callCSharp import pythonCall
```

I got an error as,

> ImportError: No module named clr

If I run the separate python file individually and its works fine. I got an error if I called it through QGIS.

I also tried adding the **clr.pyd** in qgis python path. it shows minidump error.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

You need to install this Python module in the Python that QGIS uses.
I use Windows so I have a **.bat** that opens a cmd. (change **OSGEO4W_ROOT** using your path)

```
@ECHO OFF 

set OSGEO4W_ROOT=D:\OSGeo4W64

set PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin;%PATH%
set PATH=%PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin

@echo off
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat"
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\qt5_env.bat"
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\py3_env.bat"
@echo off
path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin;%PATH%

cd /d %~dp0

call cmd
```

In the cmd we wrote:

```
python3 -m pip install clr
```

[image]

Then we open QGIS and import module

[image]